# Time reversal or complex conjugate of Dirac spinor in Peskin & Schroeder QFT book

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, spinors, time-reversal-symmetry, charge-conjugation

I have a naive question on the complex conjugate of Dirac spinor in Peskin & Schroeder QFT book (Introduction to quantum field theory), from the part below Eq.(3.137) of the book,
$$ u(\tilde{p}, -s)=-\gamma^1 \gamma^3 u(p,s)^{*}=\gamma^5 C u(p,s)^{*}, \, (1)$$
with
$$ C=i \gamma^2 \gamma^0, C^{T}=-C, \tilde{p}=(p^0, -\vec{p})$$
where $s$ is spin projection on $z$ axis. By using this equation, we obtain,
$$ u(p,s)^{*}=-\gamma^5 C u(\tilde{p}, -s),  \, (2)$$
and
$$ \left[ \bar{u}(p,s) \right]^{*}=\left[ \bar{u}^{+}(p,s)  \gamma^0 \right]^{*}=\left[ u(p,s)   \right]^{T}\gamma^0=\left[ \gamma^5 C  u(\tilde{p},-s)^*   \right]^{T}\gamma^0= \bar{u}(\tilde{p},-s) (-\gamma^5 C), \, (3)$$
Combine Eq.(2) and Eq.(3),
$$2m=\bar{u}(p,s)u(p,s)=\left[ \bar{u}(p,s)u(p,s) \right]^{*}=\bar{u}(\tilde{p},-s) (-\gamma^5 C)(-\gamma^5 C) u(\tilde{p}, -s)=-2m?   \, \, (4)$$

Question (1): where is the mistake in the Eq.(4)?

Question (2): In the helicity basis, $$ u(\tilde{p}, \lambda)=A u(p, \lambda)^{*}$$ what is the form of matrix $A$?